# Importing UTF8 data into MySQL from a file causes truncation

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a file called `person.sql` with 1 line:

`INSERT INTO Person (sFullname) VALUES ('Thomas Ågren');`

If I run the following command from the shell:

`mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -uusername -ppassword mydatabase < person.sql`

I get truncated results:

```
mysql> select sfullname from person;
+-----------+
| sfullname |
+-----------+
| Thomas    |
+-----------+
```

If I run the *same exact* insert command directly from the MySQL command line:

`mysql> INSERT INTO Person (sFullname) VALUES ('Thomas Ågren');`

I get the correct results:

```
mysql> select sfullname from person;
+--------------+
| sfullname    |
+--------------+
| Thomas Ågren |
+--------------+
```

Any ideas?  The default charset on the database and Person table are correctly set to utf8.  Here's the schema definition:

```
mysql> show create table person \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: person
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `sFullname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the text file `person.sql` was not UTF-8 encoded (although it appeared to be).  It was actually latin1 (`ISO 8859-1`).

To switch encodings, I ran:

```
iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 person.sql person-utf8.sql
```

After that, I was able to successfully import without truncation.